# What would be the possible repercussion(s) of resigning when you have been assigned to a major project?

Tags: professionalism, management, manager

I won't go into much detail but in short, my PIP was extended by a month because my manager feels I am not there where he expects me to be.

And most recently, I have been assigned to work on one of most crucial systems in our infrastructure which would need my expertise because I have been the only one who has worked exclusively on that system in the past since its in the language that I have experience with.

Project is basically a rewrite of the system in another language that other team members are comfortable in. I will be working on one of components of the system alone & will be helping a senior developer along the way as well (he's working on different component of the system).

As far as I remember, this rewrite was not going to happen for at least few months.

One of the main concerns for me has been job hunt side by side. I have had 3 interviews so far and no concrete progress yet, so I don't think I will be able to score a job offer before PIP ends.

I have sufficient savings to back myself up so I can resign without any fear of finances. In fact I have a resignation letter signed & ready right now in my bag.

So, what would be the downside(s) / repercussion(s) of leaving while I have been assigned to a major rewrite? Moreover, my manager feels that this project will probably be crucial in deciding where I stand.

Comment: Even though that's what I want to do but I am not sure if I will be able to secure a job offer before PIP ends. May be I should put more efforts into job hunt.

Comment: I think I could survive for at least 6 months or may be more. It's kind of demotivating that I have had only interviews but no job offers so far.

Comment: You're absolutely right but I know for a fact the month will go by & if there's no job offer still then I may have to resign.

Comment: No, certainly I should delay digging through my savings. Possible advantage leaving now would be I would be leaving on my own terms & I am potentially avoiding the stress & embarrassment of getting fired.

Comment: I'm not sure how the PIP, the new project and the resign are related on this question. Are you afraid of being fired after the PIP ? do you want to know what mean for your PIP the fact you got assigned to a big project? are you asking if should resign or not?

Answer (score 7):

The biggest repercussion is that you'll stop drawing a paycheck.  Remember it's often easier to get a new job while you still have your old job.

Also, it's unlikely you'll get to use this manager as a reference.  However, since you're on a Performance Improvement Plan, it's unlikely you'd want to use him anyway.

Once you have an offer in writing with no conditions, hand in your resignation and move on.

Comment: Only concerning thing is I have had 3 interviews but no job offers so far. :(

Comment: There is no repercussion other than losing the chance to contribute there. The drawback is that you have no other way to make money in the immediate term so what sucks the most is that if you're gone on your own will, you will have to deal with explaining new employers why you left.

Comment: If you have no offers, you will have an even lower chance of getting them once you resign. Companies prefer to hire people who are already employed. if you remain unemployed for over six months a good portion of the companies you apply to will automatically throw out your resume. You would be better off upping your efforts to find a job than quitting.

Comment: Additionally, in the US and possibly other countries, if they let you go, you should be able to collect unemployment, whereas if you resign, you can not.  Unemployment may not be much, but it would help stretch your 6 month financial buffer.

Answer (score 7):

> my PIP was extended by a month because my manager feels I am not there where he expects me to be...
>
> ...I have been assigned to work on one of most crucial systems in our
>   infrastructure which would need my expertise because I have been the
>   only one who has worked exclusively on that system in the past since
>   its in the language that I have experience with....
>
> ...One of the main concerns for me has been job hunt side by side. I have
>   had 3 interviews so far and no concrete progress yet, so I don't think
>   I will be able to score a job offer before PIP ends....
>
> ...So, what would be the downside(s) / repercussion(s) of leaving while I
>   have been assigned to a major rewrite? Moreover, my manager feels that
>   this project will probably be crucial in deciding where I stand.

The company has decided that a employee that is on a PIP is critical to project on a crucial system.  If I was in charge of the project the number one management goal is to get another employee or a new employee into a position so success didn't depend on the employee on a PIP.

Because you are on a PIP you should be trying to find a position, which from your question it appears you have done some of that. You should not feel an obligation to the company, because once they have somebody in place you will be considered expendable.

Resigning before you they release you or before you have a signed job offer doesn't make sense. But the PIP means that as soon as you can get a new job, your shouldn't feel bad about resigning.

Comment: If he has sufficient money in the bank, resigning before being released may make sense from a stress/mental health stance.  But that's very dependent on the person.  Agreed on everything else though